# Solving a Proxy Error (Node.js server)

Tags: node.js, proxy

Basically I get a 502 Proxy Error when running my node.js app.

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>
> The proxy server could not handle the request GET /play.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

My server looks like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/keyfile.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/crtfile.crt', 'utf8')
};

var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);

// stuff

httpsServer.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I am really sorry if this is a noob question, actually I am still a beginner in things related to node.js. Thank you for your help!

Noël.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. It's possible your problem was different, but in my case, the 502 error was coming from Apache. My httpd.conf file was referencing the same 2 certificate files that my node app was referencing.

Instead of using

`var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);`

try just

`app.listen(3000);`

I'm not sure exactly why it wasn't working. My theory is the node app was using these cert files, and apache was unable to access them, and thus creating this situation. However, just using a normal express app fixed the problem for me.

I hope this helps somebody!